# recurring payment:- invalid token error (10410)

Tags: php, paypal

following is the code that i have used for recurring payment.
but it gives error message invalid token even though i am getting the $token in $_session['TOKEN'];

```
    $nvpstr=@$nvpstr="&TOKEN=".urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
         $nvpstr.="&EMAIL=".$email;
         $nvpstr.="&PROFILESTARTDATE=".$StartDateGMT;
             $nvpstr.="&DESC=".urlencode("Pay $".$_SESSION['Payment_Amount']);
             $nvpstr.="&BILLINGPERIOD=Month";
        $nvpstr.="&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1";
        $nvpstr.="&AMT=".$_SESSION['Payment_Amount'];
        $nvpstr.="&CURRENCYCODE=USD";
        $nvpstr.="&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    function hash_call('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $nvpStr)
    {
    //declaring of global variables
    /*global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
    global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
    global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
    global $sBNCode;*/

    $PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    $PROXY_PORT = '808';


    $API_UserName  = API_USERNAME;
    $API_Password  = API_PASSWORD;
    $API_Signature = API_SIGNATURE;
    $sBNCode       = "PP-ECWizard";

    if (PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT=="sandbox") {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
        $PAYPAL_URL   = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    } else {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
        $PAYPAL_URL   = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }

    $USE_PROXY = false;
    $version   = "113";

    //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

   if ($USE_PROXY)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST . ":" . $PROXY_PORT);

    //NVPRequest for submitting to server
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=".urlencode($methodName)."&VERSION=".urlencode($version)."&PWD=".urlencode($API_Password)."&USER=".urlencode($API_UserName)."&SIGNATURE=".urlencode($API_Signature).$nvpStr."&BUTTONSOURCE=".urlencode($sBNCode);
    //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
   //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //converting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
    $nvpResArray             = deformatNVP($response);
    $nvpReqArray             = deformatNVP($nvpreq);
    $_SESSION['nvpReqArray'] = $nvpReqArray;
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        // moving to display page to display curl errors
        $_SESSION['curl_error_no']  = curl_errno($ch);
        $_SESSION['curl_error_msg'] = curl_error($ch);

        //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
    } else {
        //closing the curl
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $nvpResArray;
    }
```

your help will be really appreciated.

```
function CallShortcutExpressCheckout($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $package_name, $package_desc)
```

{

```
//------------------------------------------------------
// Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

$nvpstr = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=" . urlencode("Pay $". $paymentAmount);
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=" . $paymentAmount;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=" . $package_desc;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=" . $package_name;
$_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;
$_SESSION["PaymentType"]      = $paymentType;
//'------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//' Make the API call to PayPal
//' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
//' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
//'-------------------
$resArray = hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);    
$ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
if ($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {
    $token             = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
    $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = $token;
}

return $resArray;
```

}

The above code is working fine now but I donot know where to mention notify_url.
   So my IPN paypal is not working. I have enabled the IPN form my acc. .where I have to mention the notify_url as we mentioned the cancel_url, returnurl .

Comment: Can you post your call to SetExpressCheckout as well?

Comment: i have updated the code please check. above code is working fine but where should I mention the notifyur of IPN paypal

Comment: Unless you have a different hash_call function then this code will not work. It looks like the first argument should be `$methodName` as this is what your `SetExpressCheckout` call is sending. Can you post the output from `$_SESSION['nvpReqArray']` from when you call `SetExpressCheckout` and when you call `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`